# How to load an XmlDocument from an xml REST service response which contains a &ndash character

Tags: c#, xml

I'm getting back an xml response in which one element contains an **`&ndash`** character. This is preventing the string from loading into an `XmlDocument`. I've tried a number of things without any success. Any suggestions on how to appropriately address this issue?

I'm making the request from a console application using c#.

```
    static void Test1()
    {

        //for testing only
        string url = Properties.Settings.Default.GCAPIUrl + "?since=2013-12-01";
        //string url = Properties.Settings.Default.GCAPIUrl + "?survey_instance_id=745408";

        //uncomment this prior to going live
        //string url = Properties.Settings.Default.GCAPIUrl + "?since=" + DateTime.Today.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
        //the following will retrieve responses for the last two days
        //string url = Properties.Settings.Default.GCAPIUrl + "?days=2";

        HttpWebRequest myReq = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;

        myReq.ContentType = "application/xml";

        string username = Properties.Settings.Default.APIUserName;
        string password = Properties.Settings.Default.APIPassword;

        string usernamePassword = username + ":" + password;
        CredentialCache mycache = new CredentialCache();
        mycache.Add(new Uri(url), "Basic", new NetworkCredential(username, password));
        myReq.Credentials = mycache;
        myReq.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(usernamePassword)));

        HttpWebResponse wr = myReq.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;

        Stream receiveStream = wr.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(receiveStream);
        string strResponse = responseReader.ReadToEnd();

        string strResponseXML = RemoveInvalidXmlChars(strResponse.ToString());
        XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
        xdoc.LoadXml(strResponseXML);

        wr.Close();
    }

    static string RemoveInvalidXmlChars(string strXMLString)
    {
        strXMLString = strXMLString.Replace("&mdash;", "-");
        strXMLString = strXMLString.Replace("&ndash;", "-");
        return strXMLString;
    }
```

Comment: If the element contains `...&ndash;...`, and there is no internal or external entity declaration for &ndash;, then the appropriate way to address this is to fix the source of the XML, since it is producing invalid XML.

Comment: Welcome! I suggest you to add some code and sample response to help others understand your problem.

Comment: @forty-two, unfortunately the data is coming from another organization and thus far they have been unwilling to change their process.

Comment: @veducm, the entire snippet as it exists now has been added.  It works with the replace but going forward I don't know how reliable this will be in catching other instances of character strings that will be problematic.